# How to properly change elements of QSlider

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

[image]

Here is the style sheet:

```
QSlider{
    border: 0px solid;
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal#slider_xScaling{
    image: url(":/tools/references/dragger.png")no-repeat scroll 0 0;;
}
QSlider::add-page:horizontal#slider_xScaling{
    image:  url(":/info/references/ic-scroll-layer-track.png")no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: transparent url(":/tools/references/ic-track-fill.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

I have been experimenting on the CSS stylesheet on QT but still can't produce the proper output for this. The track is supposed to be on the middle obviously but here it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it. I also changed the height of the QSlider to make the tracker in line with the handle

```
QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: transparent url(":/tools/references/ic-track-fill.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal{
    image: url(":/tools/references/dragger.png")no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
QSlider{
    border:0px solid;
}
```